# Secure websocket (WSS) certificate signing

Tags: .net, ssl, websocket, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I have a website `https://www.foo.com` and on this site I connect to other machines with a websocket (some random ip address of a machine that has our software running on it). i.e. I connect to a websocket running on `ws://123.45.67:80`

The problem is that this site is served over HTTPS and the websocket server that I want to connect to then also requires a secure connection (WSS) and won't work with a regular websocket (WS).

The question is: **how do I sign the certificate that will reside on each websocket server that is not on my domain? Can I use the certs from the main site `https://www.foo.com` to sign a x509 cert for the websocket server on an arbitrary domain?**

I'm using [Fleck](https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck) as the websocket server

Answer (score 8):

Although the problem seems to be solved already (based on the time the question had been asked), I'll add some links for people stumbling across here.

---

1. Decide, which certificate you want to use

   - **Use *foo.com*'s certificate**
     If you want to use the same certificate as used for your page, you have to add the IP address to the certificate (ask the issuer how you can achieve this as this primarily depends on their infrastructure.
   - **Get new certificate**
     Just like you got your existing certificate, but [with the IP address](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/160809) of your websocket machine.
   - **Generate new self-signed certificate**
     If you want to generate a self-signed certificate (which issues a warning in all browsers and probably won't work without manually trusting it first), just [use OpenSSL to generate a self-signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10176685).
2. Add certificate to Fleck
   As described in [Fleck's Readme](https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck), you have to use the **wss://** protocol (with `var server = new WebSocketServer("wss://[IPAddress]:[Port]");`) and point Fleck to your certificate (x509 with both, public and private, Key) with `server.Certificate = new X509Certificate2("path/to/cert.pfx");`

This is very complicated (if not impossible) if the IP address changes frequently. Then I would suggest to use proxy listening to a (sub)domain and handling https/wss. The connection between proxy and websocket machine should then be secured physically (like connected directly) or via VPN.

---

I hope, I addressed your question(s) and my answer is clear eough. If not, feel free to comment what I can improve.